# Can you set a condition for start and end dates in a month period?

Tags: python, pandas

If a have a dataframe from which I get the total ocurrence of a value per year-month period, is there a way to change the month's start and end date?

For example, let's take this:

```
import pandas as pd

data= {
    'date': 
    [
       '2022-01-10', '2022-01-24', '2022-02-08', '2022-02-23', '2022-03-10',
       '2022-03-24', '2022-04-08', '2022-04-23', '2022-05-08', '2022-05-23',
       '2022-06-06', '2022-06-21', '2022-07-06', '2022-07-21', '2022-08-05',
       '2022-08-19', '2022-09-03', '2022-09-18', '2022-10-03', '2022-10-18',
       '2022-11-01', '2022-11-16', '2022-12-01', '2022-12-16', '2022-12-31'
    ],

    'status': 
    [
        'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'no',
        'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no',
        'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes' 
    ]
}

df= pd.DataFrame(data=data)

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

What I have now is this:

```
df['period'] = df.date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m') # <-- this creates the 'period' column

check_yes = df['status'] == 'yes'
total_yes_period = df.loc[check_yes]['period'].value_counts().sort_index() # <-- obtain total 'yes' count per period
```

However, this works when a month is taken as 'June', 'November' (i.e. first to last day). My question is, is there a way to change this to a different period? (e.g. a 'month' starts on the 10th and ends on the 9th of the next).

Comment: can you provide desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an option, I can offer if there is data for each month. Let's transform the 'period' column and create an auxiliary one with days.

Check if the day is greater than or equal to 10, then we copy the data from 'period' to the 'start' column. Next, fill in the gaps with the previous values. Create a 'finish' column using the 'start' column data + 30 days and change the number to 9.

```
import pandas as pd

df['period'] = df.date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m') 


df['period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['period'])
df['day'] = df['date'].dt.day
ind_st = df['day'] >= 10
df.loc[ind_st, 'start'] = df.loc[ind_st, 'period'] + pd.to_timedelta(9, unit='D')
df['start'] = df['start'].fillna(method="ffill")
df['finish'] = df['start'] + pd.to_timedelta(30, unit='D')
df['finish'] = df['finish'].apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(day=9))


print(df.loc[check_yes][['start', 'finish']].value_counts().sort_index())
```

Output

```
start       finish    
2022-01-10  2022-02-09    1
2022-02-10  2022-03-09    1
2022-03-10  2022-04-09    1
2022-05-10  2022-06-09    1
2022-06-10  2022-07-09    1
2022-08-10  2022-09-09    1
2022-11-10  2022-12-09    2
2022-12-10  2023-01-09    2
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to make a dictionary or dataframe in a format like CustomMonth | StartMonth | StartDay | EndMonth | EndDay
with one row for each of your custom months
From there you can query your data using this